# PHP text based on number of posts in category

Tags: php, wordpress, count, categories

I am trying to make a WordPress shortcode that should show a text containing the number of posts in a specific category and if the category is empty it should return a text saying that the category is empty.

The shortcode I have made so far kinda works. The only problem is that it keeps returning 0 posts even though there are numerous posts in that specific category.

I have tried different functions such as is_category() and get_category() but neither works. Does it make any difference that the category is related to a custom post type? The post type slug is projekt btw.

```
function imbro_aaben_projekt_shortcode() {
    $category = get_category('aaben-projekt');
    $theCount = $category->count;

    if ( $theCount > 0 ){

        return 'Total: ' . $theCount . ' posts in this category';

    } else {

        return 'There are no posts in this category';

    }
}

add_shortcode( 'imbro_empty', 'imbro_aaben_projekt_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Although not intuitive, you should be using the [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function to get a category by name. See @TheDeadMedic's  [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/how-can-i-get-category-id-by-category-name)

Comment: something like this? get_terms( 'category', array( 'search' => 'aaben-projekt' ) ); - It doesn't seem to do any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to find a solution to my own question by using [WP_QUERY](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) instead of get_category() and post_count instead of just count:

```
function imbro_aaben_projekt_shortcode() {
       $args = array(
       'cat' => 1, // category id
       'post_type' => 'projekt'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $theCount = $the_query->post_count;

    if ( $theCount > 0 ){

        return 'Total: ' . $theCount . ' posts in this category';

    } else {

        return 'There are no posts in this category';

    }
}

add_shortcode( 'imbro_empty', 'imbro_aaben_projekt_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the required result would be to use the [WP_QUERY](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) as below.

```
   $args = array(
       'cat' => 4, // category id
       'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    echo $the_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do any difference. Category ID is 1 and pst_Type is projekt.     After the $args I made the following: $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); - $postCount = $the_query->found_posts; - $theCount = $postCount->count;

Comment: well, can you debug it and see what you are getting back ?? Have you set it up correctly ?